# I am using mysql stored-procedure.My SP return dataset ,how to bind the value into crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am using mysql stored-procedure.My SP return dataset ,how to bind the value into my crystal report.

Comment: What version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Comment: I haven't done it with MySQL, but for Oracle it required an OUT parameter (SYSREFCURSOR?) for Crystal to pick up the result set.  And +1 for using a stored procedure to drive the report.

Comment: <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ReportObject.SetDataSource (dsYourDataSource);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ReportObject;
```

See [Generate ASP.NET Crystal Report using DataSet](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rsubhajit/CrystalReportwithDataSet03012006060655AM/CrystalReportwithDataSet.aspx)